# Is executing `SystemProgram.createAccount` and `Token. InitializeAccount` in different transactions considered safe?

Tags: spl-token, token, spl-token-program, runtime, systemprogram

[Solana Docs for the Token program](https://spl.solana.com/token#creating-accounts) state that:

```
It's important to note that the InitializeAccount instruction does not require the Solana
account being initialized also be a signer. The InitializeAccount instruction should be
atomically processed with the system instruction that creates the Solana account by
including both instructions in the same transaction.
```

On the other hand, [docs for the runtime](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/runtime#policy) state that:

```
Only the owner of the account may change owner.
 - And only if the account is writable.
 - And only if the account is not executable.
 - And only if the data is zero-initialized or empty.
```

So I wonder, is there any downsides/issues/risks on executing the `SystemProgram.createAccount` and `Token. InitializeAccount` in different transactions (non atomic) when creating a token account?

Answer (score 2):

I see the answer now, [the documentation](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/token-v3.1.1/token/program/src/instruction.rs#L71) in the actual token program source code goes even further and says the two transactions *'MUST'* be included in the same transaction and it explains why:

```
/// The `InitializeMultisig` instruction requires no signers and MUST be
/// included within the same Transaction as the system program's
/// `CreateAccount` instruction that creates the account being initialized.
/// Otherwise another party can acquire ownership of the uninitialized
/// account.
```